# Is the tag [exercises] really distinguished from [homework]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag [exercises](/questions/tagged/exercises) with over 70 entries.  Is this just the new [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag?  Should anything be done about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not only [exercises](/questions/tagged/exercises) (70).  There are also (at least) the tags:

- [exercise](/questions/tagged/exercise) (23)
- [programming-exercise](/questions/tagged/programming-exercise) (7)
- [book-exercise](/questions/tagged/book-exercise) (3)
- [regexercise](/questions/tagged/regexercise) (1) (the tag was removed from the question since this was written.)

These are all part of the more Generic Tag [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), and I believe they should be removed to avoid confusion.

Comment: I've added synonym suggestions for all of these [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/synonyms).

Comment: I don't think these are synonyms. xyz-exercise is a special case of exercise. There are many such tags (like apache2 is a special case of apache). They are really  `hierarchical tags`, and this feature has been declared as a strict no-no by the mods I think.

Comment: If there was an "xyz-exercise" tag for every "xyz" original tag on SO, the number would be doubled.

Comment: There's 9 questions tagged "ruby-koans".

Comment: I agree with what you say. We don't need xyz-exercise badges. They are redundant. As such, one should remove them rather than mark them as synonyms of something of which they are not synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

No. No difference and we need only one tag.

All pedagogical questions are pedagogical questions.

In some ways I would prefer [exercise](/questions/tagged/exercise) to [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) because I think it might generate less vitriol and fewer hurt feelings. But there doesn't seem to be any grassroot agreement on that.

Comment: Be that as it may, `[homework]` is clearly the best choice as a master tag right now; if a moderator wants to rename it to `[exercise]` then that would be his prerogative.

Comment: I also prefer `[exercise]` over `[homework]`, but think there is a difference.  `[homework]` suggests a student looking for help on an assignment while `[exercise]` may apply to an exercise in any programming book.  Lots of programmers read programming books that contain exercises and most of these programmers are no longer students.  (Unless one considers all programmers as lifelong students, but that's a rather philosophical opinion.)

Answer (score 2):

**All** `homeworks` are `exercises`, but all `exercises` are not `homeworks`.  (An OP may be interested in an `exercise` which is *not* her `homework`. She may not even be a student and still come up with an `exercise`). Hence these two are not the same tags.

A note about the various comments here:

'A' is a *type* of 'B' does not mean 'A' and 'B' are synonyms. Synonyms are something which are exact duplicates - like *regex* and *regular-expression*. There are many examples of hierarchical tag relationships on SO, and I think the mods have decided to never have any kind of hierarchical relationships between tags.

Comment: Of course it could happen that an exercise would not be your homework, but it could be someone else's homework. In either case, i believe it falls under the general category of "homework".

Comment: There exist a writer who is an actor does not mean all writers are actors.

Comment: There exist an actor who is a writer does not mean all actors are writers.

Comment: @athspk: Friend, what I am trying to say is all homeworks are exercises and some exercises are homeworks, and but not all exercises are homeworks. Some of the suggestions / comments in this question are as good as saying "blue should be a synonym of color" (in reality, blue is a type of color and SO tags do not support "is-a-type-of" relations).

Comment: This is all very well and good but it isn't a particularly interesting distinction.  The number of people who actually care about the difference between homework and a non-homework "exercise" like a Project Euler question is somewhere between vanishingly small and completely nonexistent.  The point of a tag is to help potential *answerers* decide whether or not the question is either interesting to them or within their area of expertise, and there are no notable cases where `[exercise]` qualifies but `[homework]` doesn't.

Comment: Is Stack Overflow an appropriate forum for publishing solutions to exercises in programming books?  For example, consider The Haskell School of Expression Blog (http://www.elbeno.com/haskell_soe_blog/?page_id=2) which publishes solutions to exercises from the book of the same name.  Do you think SO could better present and archive solutions to these exercises?  If so, what tag would best distinguish these exercises from the more common practical programming problems?  I favour `[exercise]` over `[homework]` because these solutions may interest book owners who may not be students.