# Burn the exercise tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

Can we burninate the [exercise](/questions/tagged/exercise) (meta-)tag?

*I don't think it is any different from [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) and suspect a large proportion of questions (118) are close fodder... no questions are tagged only with exercise.*

See also [Is the tag [exercises] really distinguished from [homework]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74726/is-the-tag-exercises-really-distinguished-from-homework)

Comment: Whoa, this is a tag??

Comment: Developers need exercise, because diabetes.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins exercise is for the weak...

Comment: I suppose you just take vitamins, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burninated.

Also did [example](/questions/tagged/example).

[Please care for the widows and orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged)